# Drupal: Translation template extractor works but the string cannot be found

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I'm using Translation template extractor to extract transable strings I've added to my page.tpl.php page in my zen theme files.

I've correctly exporeted zen.pot file and overwritten the previous one. The string 'random text' contained in the t('random text') function in the template is correctly added to the file.

I've refreshed cache, refreshed the tab and run cron again.

However when I search for it in the translation interface I cannot find it and therefore I cannot translate it.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to switch the language of the page containing the string at least once to save the string.

Answer (score 0):

Export a .po-file, edit it with (e.g with [Poedit](http://www.poedit.net/)) save the file and import it into Drupal.